# Android: Fit button Drawable

Tags: android, xml

> ic_heart_white_drawable.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_heart_white"
        android:width="10dp"
        android:height="10dp"
        />

</layer-list >
```

my button xml code:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_btn_like"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_heart_white_drawable"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:text="2"
            android:drawablePadding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

what i see in android studio(which is OK):

[image]

what i see in real device (which is NOT OK actually i want that tiny heart icon show on my button with size that is set on `ic_heart_white_drawable.xml` but its not working ):

[image]

what is the problem here?

Comment: you don't share enough info to actually help you, but the problem is most likely because you are using fixed size on your views - makes your screen non-responsive. share some more info of how you would want your layout to look.

Comment: use [9patch](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch).

Comment: @TamirAbutbul i provided all info that matters, the problem is that tiny heart icon would not be shown with size i specified.